# Ruby Event Machine stop or kill deffered operation

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I was wondering if I could stop execution of an operation that has been deffered.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'em-websocket'

EM.run do
  EM::WebSocket.start(:host => '0.0.0.0', :port => 8080) do |ws|
     ws.onmessage do |msg|
       op = proc do
         sleep 5 # Thread safe IO here that is safely killed
         true
       end

      callback = proc do |result|
         puts "Done!"
      end

      EM.defer(op, callback)
    end
  end
end
```

This is an example web socket server. Sometimes when I get a message I want to do some IO, later on another message might come in that needs to read the same thing, the next thing always has precedence over the previous thing. So I want to cancel the first op and do the second.

Comment: Effectively, aren't you using just one thread (other than the reactor thread) at any given point then?

Comment: I _think_ I got the answer you're looking for (it works, btw). But I don't know if it has any unwanted side-effects :/ Here's my solution: https://gist.github.com/kgrz/6826255

Comment: The question isn't exactly clear why I want to do it. Yes in this example I would be only using one thread at any given point. My real world example is that I have 2 types of messages that come in. Type 1 does a long running IO and type 2 does a variety of things. When a Type 1 message comes in it defers and takes a long time, mean while multiple type 2 messages come in, perform their op and callback.  I basically only want one Type 1 operation going on at all times and not interfere with any Type 2 operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. It is similar to the EM.queue solution, but just uses a hash.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'em-websocket'
require 'json'

EM.run do
  EM::WebSocket.start(:host => '0.0.0.0', :port => 3333) do |ws|
    mutex = Mutex.new # to make thread safe. See https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/eventmachine.rb#L981
    queue = EM::Queue.new
    ws.onmessage do |msg|
      message_type = JSON.parse(msg)["type"]
      op = proc do
        mutex.synchronize do
          if message_type == "preferred"
            puts "killing non preferred\n"
            queue.size.times { queue.pop {|thread| thread.kill } }
          end
          queue << Thread.current
        end

        puts "doing the long running process"
        sleep 15 # Thread safe IO here that is safely killed
        true
      end

      callback = proc do |result|
        puts "Finished #{message_type} #{msg}"
      end

      EM.defer(op, callback)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Don't you need to add Mutexes to this?

Comment: I tried it many times and it worked everytime. The documentation here https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/eventmachine.rb#L981 seems to agree with you so I put some of your suggestions in my answer. Should've posted that on stack instead of github and you would be getting the credit!